# Why was it dropped in Odoo.sh?

Tags: cloud, odoo, development-environment

I would like to ask about development mode in Odoo.sh

[image]

Why was it dropped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is explained in the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/13.0/odoo_sh/getting_started/branches.html).

> The databases created for development branches are meant to live around three days. After that, they can be garbage collected to make room for new databases.

You can go to the "Builds" tab and click "Rebuild" to get a new one.

Comment: Thanks mingtwo. But why it is just three days? How can i extend that time?

Comment: Other than contacting Odoo for something special, you can open the settings of your development branch, change the `Behaviour upon new commits` to `Update previous build`, and push changes (even version number) before the container gets trash collected - this will extend the life of that container. For user acceptance tests, it would be better to buy more staging containers.